# Strange inheritance in controllers

Tags: oop, cakephp, inheritance, cakephp-3.0

Today I have faced a weird behavior of my CakePHP 3 app. If the user it not logged (which is detected in the `AuthController`) it should redirect to the login page and show a message. Instead, it throws an exception from the XYController, resulting in missing credentials. The controller structure with comments, broken down and simplified:

```
class AuthController extends AppController
{

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('Auth');

        if (empty($this->Auth->getCredentials())) {
            $this->Flash->error(__('You have to sign in to access the user area.'));
            //THIS CODE IS REACHED! I'VE CHECKED

            return $this->redirect(['language' => $this->language, 'controller' => 'Pages', 'action' => 'display', 'login'], 200, true);
       }
 }



class XYController extends AuthController
{

    public function index() {
        //THE CLOUD THROWS "AccessDeniedAcception" (as excepted)
        //THE ERROR IS SHOWN IN THE BROWSER ON AN ERROR PAGE - WHY ?!?!
        $data = getSomeDataFromCloud(); 
        ...
    }
 }
```

What I completely *don't understand*, why the exception from the cloud is displayed. I thought, the `initialize()` method from the parent controller would run first and perform the redirect, before the `index()` from the child controller is ever reached. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out by myself.

One has to replace `initialize()` with `startupProcess()` and it works. [Reference](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Controller.Controller.html#_startupProcess)